# y label,angle,node problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, angle

I have three problems... 
[image]

1. I need to pass the "y label" down, where the arrow is.
2. Also, the orange node has to be lying on the arrow (I made an orange box).
3. Lastly, I need to mark the angle that I made.

I know it's a lot, but I really can't do it! I appreciate in advance.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  unit vector ratio*= 1 1 1,
  axis lines=center,
  grid={major},clip=false,
  width=20cm,height=15cm,
  y axis line style={Stealth-},x axis line style={-Stealth},
  xmin=1,xmax=900,
  ymax=2,ymin=-2900,
  xlabel={$P_{[W]}$},xlabel style={anchor=south west,align=right},
  ylabel={$Q_{[VAr]}$},ylabel style={anchor=north east}]
  \draw[green,very thick](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:631.305,0)node[midway,above]{$P=631,305W$};
  \draw[violet,very thick](axis cs:631.305,0)--(axis cs:631.305,-2905.17)node[midway,right] 
   {$Q=-2905,17VAr$};
  \draw[orange,very thick](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:631.305,-2905.17)node[midway,above] 
   {$|S|=2972,972VA$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can

1. use the `ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0,0)}}` to move the y label,
2. add `sloped` to slope the node,
3. use the `angles` library for the angles.

Note that I did not use `quotes` on purpose, and it would be probably a good idea if you looked at the `siunitx` package for the quantity with units.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,angles}
% \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
  unit vector ratio*= 1 1 1,
  axis lines=center,
  grid={major},clip=false,
  width=20cm,height=15cm,
  y axis line style={Stealth-},x axis line style={-Stealth},
  xmin=1,xmax=900,
  ymax=2,ymin=-2900,
  xlabel={$P_{[W]}$},xlabel style={anchor=south west,align=right},
  ylabel={$Q_{[VAr]}$},
  %ylabel style={anchor=north east},
  ylabel style={at={(ticklabel cs:0,0)}}]
  \draw[green,very thick](axis cs:0,0) coordinate(O)--(axis cs:631.305,0)
  node[midway,above]{$P=631,305W$}
  coordinate[pos=1](B);
  \draw[violet,very thick](axis cs:631.305,0)--(axis cs:631.305,-2905.17)node[midway,right] 
   {$Q=-2905,17VAr$};
  \draw[orange,very thick](axis cs:0,0)--(axis cs:631.305,-2905.17)
    node[midway,above,sloped] 
   {$|S|=2972,972VA$} coordinate[pos=1](A);
  \pic[draw,red,pic text=$\varphi_z$,angle eccentricity=1.5]{angle=A--O--B}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!